# Request to Jetty Jersey app terminated after 1 minute

Tags: java, jetty, streaming, google-compute-engine

I have a java jetty + jersey app that has some rest endpoints that return streaming output. A request may run several minutes. When I run it locally, long-running requests work fine. When I deploy the app to a Google Compute Engine VM, the requests always fail after 30s:

```
$ time curl -s  'https://[redacted]' -H [redacted]  -iv > /dev/null
*   Trying [redacted]...
* Connected to [redacted] port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: [redacted]
* Server certificate: thawte SSL CA - G2
> GET /[redacted] HTTP/1.1
> Host: [redacted]
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> [redacted]
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,MaxDataServiceVersion,AuthorizationFlow,Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.1.z-SNAPSHOT)
< Via: 1.1 google
< Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 13:31:05 GMT
< 
{ [932 bytes data]
* SSLRead() return error -9806
* Closing connection 0

real    0m30.133s
user    0m0.194s
sys 0m0.188s
```

From the server log:

```
    May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:189)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:335)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:125)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$ContentCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:680)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processIterations(IteratingCallback.java:166)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:126)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:303)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:720)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:751)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:130)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:124)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:328)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at com.tie.flow.bqapi.bigquery.BigQueryTableReaderService$1.write(BigQueryTableReaderService.java:62)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:78)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:60)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(LoggingFilter.java:311)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1114)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:169)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011... 67 more
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi May 27, 2016 1:38:00 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at com.tie.flow.bqapi.bigquery.BigQueryTableReaderService$1.write(BigQueryTableReaderService.java:68)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:78)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:60)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(LoggingFilter.java:311)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1114)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:189)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:335)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:125)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$ContentCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:680)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processIterations(IteratingCallback.java:166)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:126)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:303)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:720)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:751)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:130)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:124)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:328)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at com.tie.flow.bqapi.bigquery.BigQueryTableReaderService$1.write(BigQueryTableReaderService.java:62)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011... 45 more
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:169)
May 27 13:38:00 bqapi-grp-fa7g supervisord: bqapi #011... 67 more
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Don't truncate the stacktrace like that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had :

1. a low level `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`
2. which Jetty detected and reported as a `org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException`
3. which Jersey detected and attempted to report as an error 500 on the response, but couldn't as the response was already dead.

At first blush, this seems to be a bug in Jersey attempting to write a an error response on a response that has been committed already (that's a servlet spec violation).

But there's likely something else going on, as you said it seems to happen at the 1 minute mark.  This points to a configuration on your socket, or firewall, or something outside of Jetty terminating the connection after some period of time.

The part where we see ...

```
Server: Jetty(9.1.z-SNAPSHOT)
Via: 1.1 google
```

points to some interesting questions.

First, why are you running an unstable SNAPSHOT release of an old Jetty?

And the `Via: 1.1 google` could indicate a GCE / GKE / GAE environment, if that's the case, what are the networking limits present on the environment you have deployed your server on?